# How to update user info with PATCH method, Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a simple memo app with Laravel8 and want to update user-info data by using PATCH method, but when i tried, i got this error result...

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpExceptionThe PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
http://localhost/logout
```

However, according to the Request details shown on my browser, it looks like it got the PATCH method and the revised data correctly as below.

```
         Request 
     URL http://localhost/logout
  Method PATCH

         Body
  _token ********************
 _method patch
    name test_rev
    kana test_rev
   email test@email.com
```

I already checked similar questions like "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH", but it didn't help me out, so please kindly let me know what I should do to solve this problem.

Here is the details of my codes.

edit.blade.php :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('user.update', $user) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('patch')

        <div class="mt-5">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input id="name" class="block mt-1 form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}" required autofocus/>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
          <label for="kana" class="form-label">Kana</label>
          <input id="kana" class="block mt-1 form-control" type="text" name="kana" value="{{ old('kana', $user->kana) }}" required autofocus/>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input id="email" class="block mt-1 form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $user->email) }}" required autofocus/>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="location.href='{{ route('user.index') }}'">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Routing :

```
Route::get('user/index', [UserController::class, 'index'])
            ->name('user.index');

Route::get('user/edit/{user}', [UserController::class, 'edit'])
            ->name('user.edit');

Route::patch('user/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update'])
            ->name('user.update');

Route::delete('user/{user}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])
            ->name('user.destroy');
```

UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('user.index', compact('user'));
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('user.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'kana' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'payment' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,2'],
        ]);

        $user->update($validated);
        return view('user.index', compact('user'));
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->delete();
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }

}
```

If you need to see more codes or files, please kindly ask me.

Thanks for your help  in advance!

What I tried :

1. Changed the Routing to "Route::resource('user', UserController::class);", but it doesn't changed anything.
2. Changed the method name to "PUT" from "PATCH", but I got the same result.

Comment: Clear your cache and try again `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Something (possibly some middleware) is redirecting to the logout page. It might indicate there's some issue with the session data being sent.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried `php artisan route:clear`, but same result

Comment: Is this because of laravel breeze? I installed it for the user-registration, login and logout functions

Comment: Are you also using something in the front-end like e.g. inertia to handle your forms or is this just a normal submission?

Comment: i use just a normal submission

Comment: I don't think breeze would have anything that intercepts that

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I will try to find other solutions.